# Convert the provided calibration data from the standard Velodyne XML format to the node's YAML format

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to hookup the VLP-16 using ROS and on the Ubuntu 16.04.  Following your steps outlined in the Wiki I' am having problems at step 3.
http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20Velodyne%20VLP16

rosrun velodyne_pointcloud gen_calibration.py 32db.xml

I can not seem to find the xml file.

Could you provide some help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254886/convert-the-provided-calibration-data-from-the-standard-velodyne-xml-format-to-the-node%27s-yaml-format.-it-is-usually-kept-in-the-%22dsr-viewer%22-folder-on-the-cd-which-was-included-with-the-lidar./) by [Alex_MC](https://answers.ros.org/users/29310/alex_mc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know where that tutorial came from. It's not listed in the Tutorials page.

It appears to have been adapted from the 32e tutorial, and not fully converted for the VLP-16. The line you mention refers to a 32e XML file. It should not be needed for the VLP-16.

To view the points run `VLP16_points.launch` instead of `32e_points.launch`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0